How to preserve web components tags when converting markdown to html
I'd like to convert markdown files to htmls (currently I am using marked.js but open to any similar tools). My markdown files have web components but the parser does not replace web components tags (like <web-table>) and converts < to &lt;.
I know one way is to just replace those changes:
html.replaceAll("&lt;", "<").replaceAll("&quot;", '"')

Is there a better way? How can I extend the markdown parser tags recognition to include custom tags like <web-components>?
I am using marked.js but open to other similar markdown to html parsers as long as they provide an option to preserve web-components (custom tags).

https://pandoc.org and markdown-it both parse this correctly.

Thank you markdown-it rocks. If you had this as an answer I would have voted for the answer.

Both pandoc and markdown-it parse HTMl tags with dashes (common in web components) correctly.

You can wrap the web component in a block level tag, which will cause Markdown to ignore it. As a reminder, Markdown parsing does not happen inside block level HTML tags.
<div><web-table></div>

